# Supporting both asynchronous and synchronous operation for network I/O

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

First of all, I must state, that I don't have much of a C# background, so I may be missing obvious things here.

I am limited to .net 3.5 (so no async / await).

I've made a wrapper for NetworkStream, that would read "exactly N" bytes (as opposed to the traditional "up to N" bytes) and not block the current thread. What I want to do the same in the blocking way (that is, block until exactly N bytes have been received, return those bytes to the caller), but, obviously, without writing a completely separate implementation, that uses `Read`, for example.

```
internal class ReadBytesContext
{
    public Action<byte[]> Callback { get; private set; }

    public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

    public int ReadSoFar { get; set; }

    public ReadBytesContext(
        Action<byte[]> callback, 
        byte[] buffer, 
        int readSoFar)
    {
        Callback = callback;
        Buffer = buffer;
        ReadSoFar = readSoFar;
    }
}

// Network-related exception handling omitted for brevity.
public class Connection
{
    private NetworkStream _stream;

    public Connection(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public void ReadBytes(int numBytes, Action<byte[]> callback)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[numBytes];
        _stream.BeginRead(
            buffer, 
            0, 
            numBytes, 
            new AsyncCallback(ReadBytesMaybeDone),
            new ReadBytesContext(callback, buffer, 0));
    }

    private void ReadBytesMaybeDone(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = _stream.EndRead(ar);
        var context = (ReadBytesContext)ar.AsyncState;
        context.ReadSoFar += bytesRead;
        if (context.ReadSoFar < context.Buffer.Length)
        {
            _stream.BeginRead(
                context.Buffer, 
                context.ReadSoFar,
                context.Buffer.Length - context.ReadSoFar,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadBytesMaybeDone), 
                context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Callback(context.Buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this generally a valid approach to networking stuff in c#?

possibly unrelated side-question: how do I set up a catch-all handler for callbacks, that are run on the ThreadPool (that's where the delegate, that is passed to Begin* is run, right), so that uncaught exceptions in them don't crash the app?

Comment: As for the catching of exceptions, the callbacks you invoke need to have `try/catch` handlers in them. So your `ReadBytesMaybeDone` method needs to have `try/catch` handlers.

Comment: Are you planning in reusing `ReadBytes`, by passing a `bool` to specify how the operation should be done? Or are you using some other criteria to specify whether to go `sync` or `async`?

Comment: Nitpicking: "ReadSoFar = ReadSoFar;" should be `ReadSoFar = readSoFar;`

Comment: @rae1n I would rather just create another method (that will possibly call ReadBytes itself).

Comment: @Tejs yes and no. I mean, I've omitted the obvious network-related exception catching, but I definitely do *not* want to add a try / catch (to catch all exceptions) to every callback. On the other hand I don't want some exception, that managed to slip by to crash the entire app.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no higher level handler short of `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, and at that point, the app is going to be crashing anyways, and you just get the chance to log some data. If you were using TPL, you could observe the exceptions on the calling thread, but multithreaded exception handling is somewhat of a mundane thing in older versions. Try/Catch will be required.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't really a good approach because of the potential for an exception here if the network stream is closed prematurely by the client.

Have you looked at Jeff Richter's AsyncEnumerator?  I've used it in the past with .net 3.5.  Look for the Wintellect Powerthreading library in nugget.  Basically the first block of code before the yield return executes sync but as soon a the yield is hit the thread is magically put back in the threadpool and execution doesn't resume until the async operation completes.  It's old school async/await really.

```
private IEnumerator<int> ReadBytesEnumerator(AsyncEnumerator<byte[]> ae, int numbytes)
{
   byte [] buffer = new byte[numbytes];
   int totalBytes = 0;
   while(totalBytes < numbytes)
   {
     _stream.BeginRead(buffer , totalBytes , numbytes - totalBytes , ae.End(), null);

     yield return 1;

     totalBytes +=_stream.EndRead(ae.DequeueResult());

   }
   ae.Result = buffer;
}

public IAsyncResult BeginReadBytes(int numBytes, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
   AsyncEnumerator<byte []> ae = new AsyncEnumerator<byte[]>();
   return ae.BeginExecute(ReadBytesEnumerator(ae, numBytes), callback, state);
}

public byte [] EndReadBytes(IAsyncResult result)
{
  return AsyncEnumerator<byte[]>.FromAsyncResult(result).EndExecute();
}
```

Now it's up to the calling code to handled any exceptons whenever EndReadBytes is called.  To make this method sync you can just call EndReadBytes(BeginReadBytes(numBytes, null, null);  or even wrap that piece with your ReadBytes method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reuse the `Connection` class, and specifically the `ReadBytes` method, a possible implementation might be,

```
public void ReadBytes(
    int numBytes, 
    Action<byte[]> callback, 
    bool doAsync = true)
{
   if (doAsync)
       ReadBytesAsync(numBytes, callback);
   else
       ReadBytesSync(numBytes, callback);
}

private void ReadBytesSync(int numBytes, Action<byte[]> callback)
{
    var buffer = new byte[numBytes];
    var context = new ReadBytesContext(callback, buffer, 0);
    while (context.ReadSoFar < context.Buffer.Length)
    {
        var bytesRead = _stream.Read(
            context.Buffer, 
            context.ReadSoFar, 
            context.Buffer.Length - context.ReadSoFar);
        context.ReadSoFar += bytesRead;
    }

    context.Callback(context.Buffer);
}

private void ReadBytesAsync(int numBytes, Action<byte[]> callback)
{
    // Works as your current ReadBytes, which is async
}
```

Comment: Weeeell, yes, but I've mentioned the following: "What I want to do the same in the blocking way ... but, obviously, without writing a completely separate implementation, that uses Read", haven't I?

Comment: I would argue that with your `Context` class you've already reduce most of the duplication, to the point you only need to pass the `context` and do the `while` loop. In either case, though, are you looking for an implementation without using `Read`?